# How do bring a WPF Window to front?

Tags: wpf

I have created a single-instance application and want to activate an already opened window if the user starts the app multiple times. This works fine however I have the problem, that if the already opened window is beyond another applications window, I must bring it to front.

I have tried window.Focus() and window.Show() but both of them seem not to work. As a workaround I use …

```
bool oldTopMost = window.Topmost;
window.Topmost = true;
window.Topmost = oldTopMost;
window.Focus();
```

… this does the job but looks to me very ugly. Has anyone a better solution for this?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You could use [Window.Activate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.activate.aspx) instead:

```
window.Activate();
```

This is the WPF equivelent to calling [SetForegroundWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633539(VS.85).aspx).

Comment: To restore the window if it was minimized use: `if (myWindow.WindowState == WindowState.Minimized) myWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;` It will also preserve the Maximized state of the window, not reverting it back to Normal.